# how could i use "line" twice?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://127.0.0.1/static/relations/252.csv' AS line  
MATCH (a:ip{value:line.userIp}),(b:email{value:line.ucEmail})  
MERGE (a)-[rel:mayrelations]->(b)  
WITH rel, COALESCE(rel.spendTime, []) + line.spendTime AS spendTime
UNWIND spendTime as r0
WITH rel, collect(distinct r0) AS unique
set rel.spendTime= unique  


WITH rel, COALESCE(rel.eventOccurTime, []) + line.eventOccurTime AS eventOccurTime
UNWIND eventOccurTime as r1
WITH rel, collect(distinct r1) AS unique
set rel.eventOccurTime= unique
```

This syntax does not work, and raises the error: "Variable `line` not defined", I believe this means 'line' variable can be used only once. How can I use it twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What with clause do? Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699236/what-with-clause-do-neo4j)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `line` variable to the `WITH` statements:
If you check the [official docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) you can see the following instructions:

> It is important to note that WITH affects variables in scope. Any
> variables not included in the WITH clause are not carried over to the
> rest of the query.

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://127.0.0.1/static/relations/252.csv' AS line
MATCH (a:ip{value:line.userIp}),(b:email{value:line.ucEmail})
MERGE (a)-[rel:mayrelations]->(b)
WITH line, rel, COALESCE(rel.spendTime, []) + line.spendTime AS spendTime
UNWIND spendTime as r0
WITH line, rel, collect(distinct r0) AS unique
set rel.spendTime= unique

WITH rel, COALESCE(rel.eventOccurTime, []) + line.eventOccurTime AS eventOccurTime
UNWIND eventOccurTime as r1
WITH rel, collect(distinct r1) AS unique
set rel.eventOccurTime= unique